# Angularjs app redirection to external urls need solution

Tags: angularjs, twitter, paypal

I have an angular app and i have integrated it with Paypal for payments and twitter for login.. both of these require me to move to external URL hits thus completely get out of angular scope. I don't want to expose middle layers where i receive tokens any best way to implement those within angular scope or dealing with external URL's like Paypal or twitter integration.

Comment: There is no clear question.

Comment: I am asking for a better way of dealing with external URLs in angular application like of Paypal payment page or twitter login external URL hit. How to deal with the safety of tokens which i receive from these 3rd party services call back URLs.